# PHP and Active Directory Authentication allows wrong password

Tags: php, active-directory

I'm working with tying in our internal site to use Active Directory for authentication. However if you put in the wrong password and it finds the username it will still allow authentication. So basically that is telling me that it isn't really even checking whether the password matches or not.  Is there a way to make sure that actual authentication takes place?

```
<?php session_start();
include '_includes/header.php';

// form defaults
$error['alert'] = '';
$error['user']  = '';
$error['pass']  = '';

$input['user']  = '';
$input['pass']  = '';



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($_POST['username'] == '' || $_POST['password'] == '')
    {
        if($_POST['username'] == '') { $error['user'] = 'required!'; }
        if($_POST['password'] == '') { $error['pass'] = 'required!'; }
        $error['alert'] = 'Please fill in the required fields';

        $input['user'] = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $input['pass'] = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);

        include 'views/v_authentication.php';
    }
    else
    {
        $input['user'] = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $input['pass'] = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $user = $input['user'] . '@domain.local';

        $ldap = ldap_connect("name.of.ldap.server");
        if($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $user, $pass)) {

            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['type'] = $type;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $input['user'];
            $_SESSION['last_active'] = time();

            header('Location: index.php');

        } else {

                // username/password incorrect
            $error['alert'] = "Username or password incorrect!";

            include 'views/v_authentication.php';

        }
    }
}
else
{
    // check for any variables within the URL
    if (isset($_GET['unauthorized']))
    {
        $error['alert'] = 'Please login to view that page!';
    }
    if (isset($_GET['timeout']))
    {
        $error['alert'] = 'Your session has expired. Please log in again.';
    }

    // if the form hasn't been submitted, show form
    include 'views/v_authentication.php';
}

$ldap->close();

 ?>

 <?php include 'views/v_authentication.php'; ?>

 <?php include '_includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$pass is not defined in the code above and therefore null gets passed to ldap_bind().  According to the docs, this attempts an anonymous bind, which appears to be successful in your setup.  Passing $input['pass'] should do it.